# Proper way to Watch/Update a group of inputs in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, event-handling, css-selectors, smart-table

I'm currently working on learning AngularJS after years of working with JQuery.  Right now, I'm looking at implementing Smart Tables (http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) and would like to be able to automatically save the search queries to a cookie so that I can reload them when a user would return.  Ideally, I would like to have a generic way to do this so I can re-use the code by either using a single directive or DI.

In the JQuery world, I would do this:

**HTML**: Single search entry defined by *st-search* but we can have *n*-number of these all with unique id's.

```
<tr>
    <th><input st-search="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by ID" type="number"/></th>
</tr>
```

**"onChange" Javascript**: Listen to all the field updates so that, instead of alerting, I could call my storage service (probably a cookie) to save the updated search param for this table.

```
$('input[st-search]').on('change', function(event){
    var target = $(event.target);
    alert(target.attr('st-search')+'='+target.val());
});
```

**Initialization Javascript**: This would take the cookieData and apply it to all matching search fields.

```
$.each(cookieData, function(index, row) {
    $('input[st-search="'+row.stSearch+'"]').val(row.value);
});
```

Right now, I'm getting hung up on what the Angular way is to do this.  I'm trying to follow the suggestion to try and do "everything" in Angular without JQuery (["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)) but I'm not sure how to best approach this.  Can you use $scope.$watch to generically watch a lot of elements based on CSS selector (I can only find examples to do it to a specific model)? Would this be best done with a decorator either on each input or the the parent  element?  I'm really not sure where to go from here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not a pretty solution but it does seam to do what I need by combining Angular with jQuery!  I decided to go with an attribute/directive (*st-search-cookie*) on the *tr* tag that contains the search fields.  For example:

```
<tr st-search-cookie>
    <th><input st-search="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by ID" type="number"/></th>
</tr>
```

You can optionally define the *cookie-name* and *collection-name* on the directive.  Otherwise, it uses the md5 hash of all the available search fields as the collection-name.  The idea being that you have a single cookie that can have collections for many different tables instead of having lots of cookies (i.e. having to have one for every table).

Anyway, this automatically finds the default *st-search* input boxes (*input[st-search]*) as well as any with the *predicate' attribute (*input[predicate]*) that are commonly used when making custom search directives.

Hopefully someone else will find this useful or, even better, improve on it!

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module("stSearchCookie", ['ngCookies', 'angular-md5']).directive('stSearchCookie', function ($cookies, md5, $log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                'cookieName': '@',
                'collectionName': '@'
            },
            transclude: false,
            link: {
                post: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
                    // Set Defaults for scope
                    if (angular.isUndefined(scope.cookieName)) {
                        scope.cookieName = 'stSearchParams';
                        $log.log('cookie-name not defined so defaulting to "' + scope.cookieName + '"');
                    }
                    if (angular.isUndefined(scope.collectionName)) {
                        var fields = 'fieldNames=';
                        $.each(elem.find('input[st-search]'), function(i, e) {
                            fields = fields + $(e).attr('st-search') + ';';
                        });
                        $.each(elem.find('input[predicate]'), function (i, e) {
                            fields = fields + $(e).attr('predicate') + ';';
                        });
                        scope.collectionName = md5.createHash(fields);
                        $log.log('collection-name not defined so defaulting to "' + scope.collectionName + '"');
                    }

                    // Set defaults in cookie
                    var defaults = {};
                    $.each(elem.find('input[st-search]'), function(i, e) {
                        defaults[$(e).attr('st-search')] = '';
                    });
                    $.each(elem.find('input[predicate]'), function (i, e) {
                        defaults[$(e).attr('predicate')] = '';
                    });
                    var cookieData = $cookies.getObject(scope.cookieName);
                    if (angular.isObject(cookieData)) {
                        if (cookieData.hasOwnProperty(scope.collectionName))
                            cookieData[scope.collectionName] = angular.extend(defaults, cookieData[scope.collectionName]);
                        else
                            cookieData[scope.collectionName] = defaults;
                    } else {
                        cookieData = {};
                        cookieData[scope.collectionName] = defaults;
                    }
                    $cookies.putObject(scope.cookieName, cookieData);

                    // Populate from cookie
                    $.each(Object.keys(cookieData[scope.collectionName]), function (index, key) {
                        $('input[st-search="' + key + '"]').val(cookieData[scope.collectionName][key]).trigger('change').trigger('blur');
                    });
                    $.each(Object.keys(cookieData[scope.collectionName]), function (index, key) {
                        $('input[predicate="' + key + '"]').val(cookieData[scope.collectionName][key]).trigger('change').trigger('blur');
                    });

                    // Add events to update cookie on changes
                    elem.find('input[st-search]').on('change blur', function(event) {
                        var target = $(event.target);
                        var cookieData = $cookies.getObject(scope.cookieName);
                        cookieData[scope.collectionName][target.attr('st-search')] = target.val();
                        $cookies.putObject(scope.cookieName, cookieData);
                    });
                    elem.find('input[predicate]').on('change blur', function (event) {
                        var target = $(event.target);
                        var cookieData = $cookies.getObject(scope.cookieName);
                        cookieData[scope.collectionName][target.attr('predicate')] = target.val();
                        $cookies.putObject(scope.cookieName, cookieData);
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    });
})(angular);
```